# df.to_dict make duplicated index (pandas) as primary key in a nested dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I have this data frame which I'd like to convert to a dict in python, I have many other categories, but showed just two for simplicity

```
Category   Name                     Description             Price       
Diesel     Land Rover               No Description found    £ x
Electric   Tesla Model X            No Description found    £ x
```

I want the output to be like this

```
dict = {"Category": {"Diesel" : {
                                "Name": "Land Rover", 
                                "Description":"No Description Found", 
                                "Price": "£ x" },
                                           
                    "Electric" : {"Name": "Tesla Model X", 
                                  "Description":"No Description Found", 
                                  "Price": "£ x" }
                    }               
        }
```

Comment: Each category has multiple cars*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without assigning an additional column or aggregating using `list`:

```py
def collect(category):
  return category[['Name', 'Description', 'Price']].to_dict('records')

data = {'Category': df.groupby('Category').apply(collect).to_dict()}
```

I created a separate function for readability - you could, of course, pass it as a lambda too:

```py
{
  'Category': df.groupby('Category').apply(
    lambda x: x[['Name', 'Description', 'Price']].to_dict('records')).to_dict()
}
```

Comment: This is awesome thank you so much @rudolfovic

Answer (score 1):

You can start by creating a dictionary for each record and then group by category to create the final dictionary format desired.

```
df['dict'] = df[['Name', 'Description', 'Price']].to_dict("records")

dictionary = dict()
dictionary['Category'] = df.groupby('Category')['dict'].apply(list).to_dict()
```